# I want to send warning logs generated to a server machine

Tags: python

I wish to receive logs generated while executing a program ( all logs whose level is above warning) through mails. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Generally, almost everything is possible. - But on a more serious note: What are your ideas or first steps? This community is trying to help you, but we are not doing your job.

Comment: [click here](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/)
You can go through it once...

Comment: I got the answer:SMTPHandler instances send messages to a designated email address